# UITableView Setting different Images

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Can somebody help me out with an example code of how to to this: I have my UITableView and I already set everything, I want that when you click on one cell it gives you an image, wich I already have, there are 8 images, and therefore 8 cells with different names each, so what can I do??its for example my cells names, "apple", "orange", "banana" and so on, so I need one picture for each, but of course in order, I mean the banana with the banana and so on. I know i´ts very simple, but I haven´t found any example for this, and I´m very new at all this, Thanks, XD...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is two NSArrays built with the text descriptions and the images (this could also be done with one `NSArray` and and `NSDictionary` with two key-value pair).  In that case, each dictionary would have two key-value pairs (one for the text and one for the image).

But for the sake of simplicity, we'll use two NSArrays.

So something like this:
In `viewDidLoad`:

```
textArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Banana",
                          @"Orange",
                          @"Apple",
                          @"Grape",
                          @"Pineapple",
                          @"Apricot",
                          @"Pear",
                          @"Kiwi", nil];
imagesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Banana.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Grape.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pineapple.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Apricot.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pear.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Kiwi.png"],
                        nil];
```

*** This assumes you have png images in your project named as described above.

Then for the `UITableView` datasource and delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark - UITableView Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.   
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return count of our text array
    return [textArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tvCell"];


    cell.textLabel.text = [textArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Do whatever you need to here
}
```

Complete project can be downloaded [HERE](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3660978/SOImageTVC.zip) (I will leave it up for the next 24 hours)

Comment: Thank you very much @ElJay for your answer and the file, but i´m sorry to tell you that it´s not working, with the file you gave me, when I run it, it breaks. Then I tried it in my file, and the same problem, it crashes.By the way in the comment //Do whatever you need to here. Shoulnd´t there be the important code I need?? the one linking the images array with the text array? I hope you can help me, and I appreciate the file and the help, thanks!! XD.

Comment: You will probably need to change the code signing for it to run on your machine.

Comment: I did change it, I mean I have no errors, but when I run it, the simulator crashes, and in the method tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath, what should I put?

Comment: OH I see the problem, the code you gave me was to put an image on each row right?, but what I needed was that when you select a row it navigates you to another view, like a detailview, with the image of the fruit for example, can you help me with that?

Comment: Heading to bed now, but I will revise the project and put it back up tomorrow am (US Central Time).

Comment: Project updated (just download the same zip file again).  Contact me through this site (www.irockios.com) if you have further questions.  Will leave project up there for another 24 hrs.

Comment: Thank you very much @ElJay you´ve been very helpful, thanks a lot...XD

Answer (score 0):

There are of course several ways to do this. One of the simplest way which involve no code at all is to use the scenario builder in Xcode.

1 - add a UITableViewController to an application that is using a scenario
2 - select the table view in this controller and in the properties, set it to "static list" (I don't remember the exact name of this property - I will edit my answer to add it if you can't find it)
3 - edit the number of items in the list and each cell to have the label you want
4 - add some UIController to the scene and add the images inside
5 - link each table cell to the matching controller with a segue (ctrl-click and drag or option-click)
6 - click build & run.

That's it - not one line of code!

Ps: I am on my iPhone right now but I could post a full example if you need it. It's actually a pretty cool trick for quick prototypes.

Comment: Well thanks, but I really would like some code, so I can learn, besides for some reason the xcode 4.3 its difficult to understand, and I´m building my app in 3.2, so if you could give me an example code, I would really appreciate it...XD

Comment: If you are learning now, you should try to learn with xcode 4.3. It will be easier to follow and it does makes a lot of things easier for the developer. Have a look at the tutorial named "Your second iOS app" (included in the help of Xcode), I believe it covers exactly what you want to do, in code and in storyboards.